# when i import database this type of error occure..what can i do?

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
Error
SQL query:




--
-- Database: `dbase`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin_task`
--

CREATE TABLE `admin_task` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accepted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a table, you first off have to select the database where you want to create it in.

You can simply use this command;

```
USE DatabaseName;
```

After you executed this query you can now execute your "CREATE TABLE" query without the program giving you this error, if your query has no syntax errors in it at least.

If you have not created a database for this table yet, then create one using the following line of code;

```
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseName;
```

After you execute this query you should made your database where you can create this table in.

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1):

You need to either create a database first or select an existing database and connect to it, *and then* you can import your script.

Answer (score 0):

1)First Select Database where you want to add table
then query by selecting sql tab

2) if database present
then use
"database_name." before table name

- Database: dbase

  CREATE TABLE dbase.admin_task ( username varchar(50) NOT NULL, accepted tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;